# How can i get this tree to work properly?

Tags: recursion, data-structures, tree, binary, binary-tree

I cannot get this tree to act correctly. i keep getting exit error codes. What is going on with the tree and how would i use the search function in main? it seems the methods are coded correctly but i am not using it correctly in main.  i keep geting exit errors that are not 0 and none of the methods i try to use in the main function work. now i am just typing to fill in space because apparently my post is mostly code and not enough text!

```
//Binary Tree Practice
#include <iostream>

struct node{
int data;
node* right;
node* left;
};
class bTree{
public:
bTree(){
    root=NULL;
}
~bTree(){
    destroyTree();
}
void addNode(int key);
node *search(int key);
void destroyTree();

private:
node* root;
void addNode(int key,node*nod);
node *search(int key, node *leaf);
void destroyTree(node*&node);


}; 
node *bTree::search(int key)
{
return search(key, root);
}
void bTree::destroyTree()
{
destroyTree(root);
}
void bTree::addNode(int key)
{
if(root!=NULL)
    addNode(key, root);
else
{
    root=new node;
    root->data=key;
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
}
}
void bTree::addNode(int key, node* nod) {//ADD a node in correct position.
if (key < nod->left->data) {
    if (nod->left != NULL)
        addNode(key, nod->left);//RECURSION traverse tree to the left until 
find a NULL node

    else {//When NULL node is found
        nod->left = new node;
        nod->left->data = key;
        nod->left->left = NULL;
        nod->right = NULL;
        std::cout<<"node added"<<std::endl;
    }
} else if (key > nod->right->data) {
    if (nod->right != NULL)
        addNode(key, nod->right);//RECURSIONTraverse right till find a null 
node

    else {//NULL node found
        nod->right = new node;//Create new node
        nod->right->data = key;//set NODE data to KEY
        nod->right->right = NULL;
        nod->left = NULL;
    }
 }
}
node *bTree::search(int key, node *leaf)
{
if(leaf!=NULL)
{
    if(key==leaf->data)
        return leaf;
    if(key<leaf->data)
        return search(key, leaf);
    else
        return search(key, leaf->right);
}
else return NULL;
}


void bTree:: destroyTree(node*&node){
if(node==NULL){
    destroyTree(node->left);
    destroyTree(node->right);
    delete node;
}
}
int main() {

bTree *trees=new bTree();
trees->addNode(10);
trees->addNode(6);
trees->addNode(14);
node *check;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing your addNode function with signature *void bTree::addNode(int key, node* nod)* does is this:

```
if (key < nod->left->data) {
```

The problem with your code is that nod->left will lead to a crash, since the left node has not been initialized and leads to an unauthorized memory access, or what is called a *segmentation fault*. Let's go through the main loop.

1. addNode(10) - The addNode function with signature *void bTree::addNode(int key)* is called, root is null, so root is created with left and right nodes set to NULL.
2. addNode(6) - The addNode function with signature *void bTree::addNode(int key)* is called, root is NOT null, so addNode with signature *void bTree::addNode(int key, node* nod)* is called. Then nod->left, and crash.

This is a common problem in low level programming, and my advice to you is to put debug prints inside the functions to see which parameters entered, and where exactly the code crashed. If you can pinpoint the exact line that leads to the crash (in thise case the line with nod->left) you can solve these kinds of problems more easily in the future.

In order to fix your issue, simply make sure to initialize the left and right nodes before you access them.